# Salesforce Trigger: when does trigger.isBefore return true or false? Depending on what?

Tags: triggers, salesforce

I often see IsAfter and IsBefore methods used in many SFDC trigger, but I cannot understand the logic that gives me true or false value in return for these methods!
So, generically, I somewhere I have Trigger.isBefore (the same question is valid for IsAfter) , how can I understand if this boolean will be true or false? Depending on what?
I read the docs for these methods, but simply I cannot understand why Trigger.isBefore will return me true or false! This thing is annoying me, I think I will never undertand fully this concept, please help me!

Answer (score 2):

`Trigger.isBefore` will only return true if it has one or more of the following in the conditions:

- `before delete`
- `before insert`
- `before update`

**And** the trigger is firing for one of those conditions.

The same applies for `Trigger.isAfter` except you need to substitute "after" for "before" in the conditions.

Most of the time you are going to be dealing with steps 3 and 6 in [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).

1. Loads the original record from the database or initializes the record for an upsert statement.
2. Loads the new record field values from the request and overwrites the old values.
3. **Executes all `before` triggers.** [`Trigger.isBefore` will be true]
4. Runs most system validation steps again, such as verifying that all required fields have a non-null value, and runs any user-defined validation rules. The only system validation that Salesforce doesn't run a second time (when the request comes from a standard UI edit page) is the enforcement of layout-specific rules.
5. Saves the record to the database, but doesn't commit yet.
6. **Executes all `after` triggers.** [`Trigger.isAfter` will be true]

Answer (score 0):

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm explains that isBefore returns true if the trigger was fired before any record was saved, and isAfter returns true if this trigger was fired after all records were saved.

The page also has a useful example showing how this can be used to have code which only executes for specific trigger conditions.

Comment: I read all that pages and examples but the logic is still impossible to understand for me: ok, isBefore returns true if the trigger was fired before any record was saved, but how can I know if the trigger was fired before or after any record was saved?

Comment: You write the trigger code to beahve appropriately before and after, so e.g. in the before state you might do validation, and in the after state you might cause changes in other records. From http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers.htm a suggestion is that might involve something like generating log records in an audit table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the "Order of Execution of a Save" for DML Events. If you issue a record save on the Force.com platform, a lot of things happen behind the scenes, including the execution of "before" or "after" triggers. When you save a record, one of the first steps is that the before triggers associated with the record's sObject type are executed. One of the final steps is that the after triggers are executed. Therefore isBefore is simply telling you: yes, for this save event, the platform has reached the point in the Order of Execution of a Save in which it will now automatically fire a before trigger.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Even if, this question is just a bit old, and now I can move much better than a years ago in this field !